# How to work with CryptoAPI via C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cryptoapi, mscapi

There is a group of CryptoApi functions which works with crypto service providers (CSP).

```
CPAcquireContext
CPCreateHash
CPDecrypt
CPDeriveKey
CPDestroyHash
CPDestroyKey
CPDuplicateHash
CPDuplicateKey
CPEncrypt
CPExportKey
CPGenKey
CPGenRandom
CPGetHashParam
CPGetKeyParam
CPGetProvParam
CPGetUserKey
CPHashData
CPHashSessionKey
CPImportKey
CPReleaseContext
CPSetHashParam
CPSetKeyParam
CPSetProvParam
CPSignHash
CPVerifySignature
```

Yes, I know that there is System.Cryptography namespace. But I don't need their implementations.

Is there any ready library which provides a .NET wrapper to these functions?

Comment: The  System.Security.Cryptography Namespace *is* a wrapper around the Windows CryptoAPI.

Comment: Ok, what class(es) should I use to work with third party CSP?

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm trying to create my own csp dll

Answer (score 3):

There has been an extended article on MSDN about this topic:

[Extending .NET Cryptography with CAPICOM and P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867087.aspx)

An article on using [CryptoAPI Certificate Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867080.aspx) from .Net.

Some P/Invoke declarations lifted from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2007/11/23/p-invoking-cryptoapi-in-net-c-version.aspx) that shows the p/Invoke definitions for it:

> [snip] code sample too large for SO [/snip]

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use P/Invoke to pull the functionality into your C# application.
Here's an (old) article on MSDN about using P/Invoke and CryptoAPI in C#:

[Extending .NET Cryptography with CAPICOM and P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867087.aspx)

It's for .Net 1.1, but the concepts are still the same.